# Цитата. Что с выделением?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, цитата, авторская-пунктуация

Не могу объяснить недостачу закрывающих (избыток открывающих) кавычек в этом фрагменте. Прошу помочь понять причину! Здесь автор приводит строки из книги «Геометрия словенски землемерие» 1708 г.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Русская техническая литература первой четверти XVIII в., В.В. Данилевский. АН СССР 1954)

Answer (score 1):

Такое ощущение, что они взяли за основу [рекомендации](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:3fUloTPkVcoJ:https://www.gsbe.co.uk/grammar-quotation-marks.html%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ru) по пунктуации в британском английском (что-то случилось с самим сайтом, поэтому я взял кэшированную версию).